# Trouble getting viewport size with overflowed images using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, viewport

I've been stuck on this annoying bug for a couple hours now. I need to get the viewport of the browser window (specifically, just the height of the visible region in the browser). Looking around, I found that jQuery can do this:

```
$(window).height()
```

This value is accurate when I first load the page, but with my site I'm working on, if I resize the browser window, `$(window).height()` now becomes the height of the entire document (which includes the nonvisible section. [I simplified my site so that it demonstrates the problem I'm running into](http://rwell.org/albums/). Make sure the images are overflowing off the page to demonstrate my issue.

Comment: Can you set a DOCTYPE? For w/e reason in IE if I manually set the doctype it returns the right value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly specifying the doctype fixed it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```